# BoofCV Structure from motion (Sfm) by Example

Tags: java, computer-vision, boofcv, structure-from-motion

I am playing around with [**structure from motion** (Sfm)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_from_motion) and 3D model reconstruction for the first time. The end result is to be able to generate a (fairly accurate) 3D model from a series of images.

Being a JVM developer, my natural inclination was to look for an available Java lib. I found [BoofCV](http://boofcv.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) which seems to be an active project with decent features & capabilities. But I took a half-day and followed their Sfm examples and wasn't real happy with the results. If you're interested in reproducing them I made a [little example project](https://github.com/hotmeatballsoup/boofcv-sfm-example) that you can clone and build yourself. But the TL;DR of that is that the code was *supposed* to render a 3D model of this chair:

[image]

...but instead gave me something that only *very* vaguely resembles a chair:

[image]

Very awesome that it can even do this (kudos to the BoofCV team!!!), but still not what I was expecting (then again, being brand new to CV, perhaps this result is completely expected and represents best-in-show Sfm capabilities, I dunno!). I compare these results to the Python Photogrammetry Toolbox ("PyPT") library results of a [3D generated skull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_from_motion#/media/File:SfM_PPT_GUI_vs_PHOTO.png), and, well, BoofCV just leaves me wanting a little more...

That PyPT example clearly demonstrates awesomeness, and apparently Google uses [PMVS](http://www.di.ens.fr/pmvs/) and [CMVS](http://www.di.ens.fr/cmvs/) for its 3D mapping capabilities. So there are *clearly* other open source libs out there that can get the job done...and well.

So I ask:

1. Is the example code in my project (linked above) just not fully leveraging BoofCV's Sfm/reconstruction capabilities?; or
2. Does BoofCV just not work as well as these other libs? If so, does anybody know offhand what could be contributed to BoofCV (feature/capability-wise) to get it up to par with these other libs?; or
3. Am I just interpreting these results incorrectly, and perhaps the chair results above *are* just as accurate as what these other libraries will give me, but I'm just not looking at it the right way?!?

Comment: Update: it looks like PyPT is just a GUI/usability/convenience wrapper *over* Bundler/PMVS/CMVS. I might try to get those three tools working together and then see if I can whip up some JNI to call them from inside a JVM process.

Comment: Or, contrarily, to use Thrift to communicate between a JVM process and PyPT (if possible, probably not, I dunno).

Comment: Turns out SFM software just produces **sparse** point clouds, and so the result I posted above is totally expected. The idea is that you take this sparse point cloud (that the SFM component outputted) and use it as input to a Multi-View Stereo (MVS) software, forming a tool pipeline. The MVS software then converts this into a **dense** point cloud which accurately represents the image. Problem is, BoofCV doesn't do MVS (that I can tell). So I found a modern, open source SFM/MVS pipeline called [OpenMVS](https://github.com/cdcseacave/openMVS) and I'll try that out next.

Comment: thank you so much for taking your time to post this. I'm now in your exact same shoes from 3 years ago. How did you manage to solve this? Do you recall? I'm going to try OpenMVS but anything you can offer would be excellent.